# Flutter in Android Studio shows errors everywhere but the code is correct

Tags: android, flutter

[It seems to show errors about packages' imports but I can run the code and it perfectly works. So the problem to solve is: How can I fix that bug?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkhAz.png)

```
    [√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.4, on Microsoft Windows [Versione 10.0.18362.418], locale it-IT)
    • Flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.4 at C:\Users\eddie\flutter
    • Framework revision cc949a8e8b (2 weeks ago), 2019-09-27 15:04:59 -0700
    • Engine revision b863200c37
    • Dart version 2.5.0


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\eddie\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\java
    • Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 40.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 191.8423
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[!] Android Studio
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.2\bin\idea64.exe
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    X android-studio-dir = C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.2\bin\idea64.exe
    X Android Studio not found at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.2\bin\idea64.exe
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.
    • Consider removing your android-studio-dir setting by running:
      flutter config --android-studio-dir=

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

I've also tried uninstalling Android Studio but it's still there. Unfortunately, I can't remove all the configuration files because I have the keystore for an app. Help me as soon as possible I have some work to do and I have no backup PCs

Answer (score 0):

First, go to android studio and install the flutter packages and then run flutter doctor

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled android studio deleting all the configuration files and whatever related to it. Now it works. It's not a proper solution since it's like I had something broken and I just bought a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to go to File/Invalidate Caches / Restart and click Invalidate Caches and Restart

Answer (score 0):

You have not installed flutter and dart packages. You first need to install them in android studio([This documentation might be useful](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/editor)) and then run the following commands.

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```